# jquery slider in asp.net with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to get a slider to display on the screen but I am hitting a wall. Everything I've read says it should work... Here's my code.

```
<%@ Page Title="ClinicalTrial.gov" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SeanTiffanyJoshua.aspx.cs" Inherits="DrugDevelopmentGame.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <link href="SeanTiffanyJoshua.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#slider").slider();
        });
    </script>

    <div id="slider"></div>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server">slider</asp:Label>

</asp:Content>
```

What am I doing wrong? please please please help me :(

Comment: Looks like you are missing reference to jqueryUI.js and jQueryUi.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing reference to jQueryUI.js and jQueryUI.css. Add reference to them..

```
<%@ Page Title="ClinicalTrial.gov" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SeanTiffanyJoshua.aspx.cs" Inherits="DrugDevelopmentGame.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <link href="SeanTiffanyJoshua.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#slider").slider();
        });
    </script>

    <div id="slider"></div>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server">slider</asp:Label>

</asp:Content>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54thmbtj/)