# Creating slider input on the run ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

is it possible to create slider on the run with just C# and ASP not M V C not other languages ?
like i can create hyperlinks using `HyperLink` class then append it to a parent in the HTML form

Comment: Sliders exist on the client side. To make them happen, the server has to serve CSS and JS files. It therefore does not matter what technology the server is based on, as long as it can serve these files.

Comment: could you provide me with some code please so i know how you did it ?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/slider/ try this one, or any other jquery ones

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804704/jquery-slider-in-asp-net-with-bootstrap

Comment: thanks a lot will try this one